# Sharepoint 2013 - Fetch last modified date of the list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

Trying to fetch the last modified time of Sharepoint list. Found a code that states the author and modified by. It was working fine when it had the line

```
<input id="btnGetFieldUserValue" onclick="getFieldUserValue()" type="button" value="Get Created by and Modified by"/>
```

but when i changed to

```
<div id="create" onload="getFieldUserValue()"> &#160;</div>
```

No repose in the content editor webpart of sharepoint 2013.

Help.

My task is to show the last updation time of the list. Any other way to do that, please share.

```
    var listItem;
    var list;
    var clientContext;

    function getFieldUserValue() {

        this.clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        if (this.clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
            var webSite = clientContext.get_web();
            this.list = webSite.get_lists().getByTitle("Resource Readiness");
            this.listItem = list.getItemById(1);
            clientContext.load(this.listItem);
            this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadFailed));
        }
    }

    function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
        var fieldUserValueCreatedBy = this.listItem.get_item("Author");
        var fieldUserValueModifiedBy = this.listItem.get_item("Editor");
        document.getElementById("create").innerHTML = fieldUserValueModifiedBy.get_lookupValue() ;
        alert("Created By: " + fieldUserValueModifiedBy.get_lookupValue() + "\n Modified By: " + fieldUserValueModifiedBy.get_lookupValue() + "\n");
    }


    function OnLoadFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for script files:

```
     function getFieldUserValue(){
           SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadContext, 'sp.js');
     }
     function loadContext() {
            this.clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        if (this.clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
            var webSite = clientContext.get_web();
            this.list = webSite.get_lists().getByTitle("Resource Readiness");
            this.listItem = list.getItemById(1);
            clientContext.load(this.listItem);
            this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadFailed));
        }
     }

    function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
        var fieldUserValueCreatedBy = this.listItem.get_item("Author");
        var fieldUserValueModifiedBy = this.listItem.get_item("Editor");
        document.getElementById("create").innerHTML = fieldUserValueModifiedBy.get_lookupValue() ;
        alert("Created By: " + fieldUserValueModifiedBy.get_lookupValue() + "\n Modified By: " + fieldUserValueModifiedBy.get_lookupValue() + "\n");
    }


    function OnLoadFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Comment: Not working.. Should i use this code in content editor or Script editor(though tried both). No result

Comment: Add to script editor: _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("getFieldUserValue");